# cakephp console without prompt (-f option?)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cake-console

Some CakeConsole commands (such as `schema update`) needs to confirm the operation by user. (`Are you sure…` messages)

I want to use it under Puppet (automatic installation) so there is no actual user to enter `yes` for confirmation.

Is there any option to force console to do it? Without asking user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There's an option for that

> **--yes, -y         Do not prompt for confirmation. Be careful!**

```
-> app/Console/cake schema update --help

Welcome to CakePHP v2.8.0-dev Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/www/someapp.dev/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:
cake schema update [options]

Options:

--help, -h        Display this help.
--verbose, -v     Enable verbose output.
--quiet, -q       Enable quiet output.
--plugin, -p      The plugin to use.
--path            Path to read and write schema.php (default:
                  /var/www/someapp.dev/app/Config/Schema)
--file            File name to read and write.
--name            Classname to use. If its Plugin.class, both name and
                  plugin options will be set.
--connection, -c  Set the db config to use. (default:
                  default)
--dry             Perform a dry run on create and update commands.
                  Queries will be output instead of run.
--snapshot, -s    Snapshot number to use/make.
--force, -f       Force "generate" to create a new schema
--yes, -y         Do not prompt for confirmation. Be careful!
```

**However** the `yes` option wasn't added [until 2.5](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/a54e8f238e7a8fc5ba4d877ec5e3d1786a71bf58) - if you're using an earlier version of 2.x, you'll need to upgrade to have this option available.